# Install nvidia drivers without a desktop

Tags: server, nvidia, gpu-driver

I would like to install a Nvidia Driver on a pure Ubuntu server.

I've already tried installing package `nvidia-driver-495`, but a desktop environment was installed automatically.

How can I install a Nvidia driver and get stuffs like `nvidia-smi` working while keeping my machine from running a desktop?

Comment: Can you [download the drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) straight from NVIDIA, and just use that command line installer? That might work for you

Comment: There are "server" versions already available in the repositories.

Comment: @ChanganAuto +1 although it looks like the nomenclature may have changed from "server" to "headless" ex. it's `nvidia-driver-450-server` but `nvidia-headless-495` ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:
Installing `nvidia-driver-470-server` worked for me.

Hint:

- Package `nvidia-headless-495` isn't for me because of the lack of `nvidia-smi` etc.
- The latest "New Feature" branch driver version is 495 but `nvidia-driver-495-server` doesn't exsist (as of now). That mislead me because autocomplete doesn't give me an "server" package when installing that version.

Thanks for comments from cocomac, ChanganAuto and steeldriver!